# New keyboard layout for Albanian?

Tags: keyboard-layout, language-support, input-language

I would like to have at least one alternative keyboard layout for the Albanian language provided as a distro update or as part of future releases of Ubuntu. Could anyone let me know where or how I could submit a proposal to the developers?

The "official" Albanian layout is somewhat inadequate and highly unpopular among Albanian users. For that reason, I have created and published two alternative layouts that take into account the market in Albanian-speaking countries (dominated by US mechanical keyboards) and user preferences (for a layout similar to the US model).

You may find more information about the layout on Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albanian_keyboard_layout#Plisi) or on my Albanian-language website (http://www.plisi.al/softwer/tastiera-plisi-d) where you may also download the installation files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, but I think you may want to  submit a bug report against the [xkeyboard-config](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xkeyboard-config) package in Ubuntu together with a patch or merge proposal to the Bazaar branch.

However, xkeyboard-config is an upstream package, and the chances for a patch to be included in Ubuntu increase if you also file a bug + patch to the [upstream maintainer](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=xkeyboard-config).

Comment: Thank you. I just submitted this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xkeyboard-config/+bug/1279898